# Sinch java error

Tags: sinch

i am using sinch from java, i recently reput credit to the account, and now when i try to send message i get succes message, but the sms isn't send. Following the link https://messagingapi.sinch.com/v1/sms/162393899 i get this

> {"errorCode":40107,"message":"Invalid authorization key:
>   vivi******@gmail.com","reference":"BA:vivi******@gmail.com_GtIfKPDMJEKL4VJWR0kkJQ"}

the code

```
try {
            String phoneNumber = "+40732******";
            String appKey = "*****";
            String appSecret = "****";
            String message = "Test";
            URL url = new URL("https://messagingapi.sinch.com/v1/sms/" + phoneNumber);
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setDoOutput(true);
            connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
            String userCredentials = "application\\" + appKey + ":" + appSecret;
            byte[] encoded = Base64.encodeBase64(userCredentials.getBytes());
            String basicAuth = "Basic " + new String(encoded);
            connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", basicAuth);
            String postData = "{\"Message\":\"" + message + "\"}";
            OutputStream os = connection.getOutputStream();
            os.write(postData.getBytes());
            StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
            String line;
            while ( (line = br.readLine()) != null)
                response.append(line);
            br.close();
            os.close();
            System.out.println(response.toString());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: `Invalid authorization key: vivi******@gmail.com"` seems pretty clear. You're giving it your email when it expects a key.

Comment: seems, but i am not sending the email address, i am sending the key ...